# Inserting Elements of 1D array to specific location in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, concatenation, nested-for-loop

Attempting to combine 1 & 2 dimensional list/arrays containing strings using the `insert()` method.

However getting a specific element from the 1D list and placing that into a specific location within the 2D list is where Im stuck.

Here is a simplified version of what the goal is;

```
#2D list/array
list1= [['a1','b1'], ['a2','b2'] , ['a3','b3']]

#1D list/array
list2= ['c3','c2','c1']

#desired output
list1= [['a1','b1','c1'], ['a2','b2','c2'] , ['a3','b3','c3']]
```

Here is the isolated block of code from the script which Im trying to attempt this with;

```
#loop through 1D list with a nested for-loop for 2D list and use insert() method.
#using reversed() method on list2 as this 1D array is in reverse order starting from "c3 -> c1"
#insert(2,c) is specifying insert "c" at index[2] location of inner array of List1

for c in reversed(list2):
    for letters in list1:
        letters.insert(2,c)

print(list1)
```

output of the code above;

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c3', 'c2', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c3', 'c2', 'c1'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'c2', 'c1']]
```

What is the best & most efficient way to go about returning the desired output? Should I use the `append()` method rather than `insert()` or should i introduce list concatenation before using any methods?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: A simple and efficient way is to use "enumerate" in the outer for-loop (and removing the inner for-loop). It allows to receive an index in parallel to the item. You can use this index on "list1" to access and modify the respective sublist. A bit harder to understand is the use of "zip" instead to have sublist and item from "list2" in parallel directly.

Comment: I see so im reading here using the built-in enumerate function, returns as an emumerate object as a tuple with indexes. would i apply this function to the 1D array list2  first? ill read more on the built in zip() function as well

Comment: Actually only to the (reversed) "list2".

Comment: okay ive attempted your suggestion of removing the inner for-loop and applying the enumerate function in the outer for loop to the reversed list2 as such;                   ```for c in enumerate(reversed(list2)): print(list (c))```                                                                                                           
the output i received was ```[(0, 'c1'), (1, 'c2'), (2, 'c3')]``` which is good. Now im confused on how to use these index to access and modify the sublist in list1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can achieve this via a list comprehension using `enumerate` or `zip`. You can use `enumerate` to get the index and sublist from `list1`, using the `index` to select the appropriate value from `list2` to append to each sublist:

```
list1 = [l1 + [list2[-i-1]] for i, l1 in enumerate(list1)]
```

or you can `zip` together `list1` and the reversed `list2`:

```
list1 = [l1 + [l2] for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2[::-1])]
```

Or you can just use a simple `for` loop to modify `list1` in place:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i].append(list2[-i-1])
```

For all of these the output is:

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
```

Comment: Hey there @Nick, thanks for the response with multiple variations of how to tackle this. I will go through and apply each one to understand what is happening under the hood. However i do have a question regarding the index ```[-i-1]``` for ```list2``` for the first and third solutions. Is that index stating "negative i at negative index 1" or is that "negative i minus 1"?

Comment: @HWFord16 it's negative(i+1) i.e. negative i minus 1. Since positive indexes start at 0, but negative indexes (reading from the end of the list backwards) start at -1, you need to subtract 1 from the negated positive index to get the corresponding negative index.

Comment: I see that makes sense. Okay last question for you. The function within a function `range(len(list1))` how is that not throwing a "TypeError"?  The reason I ask is, before i posted this question i tried to use those functions individually for `list1` and the error was " int object is not iterable" or "list cannot be interpreted as integer". When using these built in functions in this fashion, how is this getting around the error? My understanding for this is, "for "i" in range between 0 and length of list1" provides a integer range for the loop to iterate "i" through. Is this correct?

Comment: @HWFord16 that is exactly correct; `len(list1)` returns an integer, the length of `list1` and then `range` returns an sequence that counts from 0 to `len(list)-1`, and `i` then takes each of the values of that sequence in turn, 0, 1, ..., len(list)-1